# Php How do you redirect without copying the same url query

Tags: php

I am validating a form on a page and I need to redirect back to the same page with the same url query and a additional `&valid=false` at the end of the query when redirected.

How would you do this so that the url is not repeated on redirect:

```
http://test.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&valid=false&a=1&b=2&valid=false
```

I am using  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you have? What are you trying to do? What's the code that's causing the problem? This isn't your first or second question here. Please learn how to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here is a simple one:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (!isset($_GET['valid'])) {
    $url.='&valid=false';    //assuming there are always additional parameters, otherwise you must check whether to use '?' or '&' 
}
```

But you can also use parse_url(), strpos(), regular expressions etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use of [http_build_query()](http://php.net/http_build_query) after modifying parameters:

```
<?php
    $_GET['a'] = 1;
    $_GET['b'] = 2;
    $_GET['valid'] = 'true';

    $url = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
?>
```

Like that, if `$_GET['valid']` is not defined then it will be created, else it will be modified.